# why a for loop skip the first element after the list in the for loop has been changed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I intended to remove the elements with `'0'` in the end or only with `'0'`, and my codes are:

```
s = ['a0', 'b0', '0', 'c', 'd']
for x in s:
    if x[-1] == '0' or x == '0':
        s.remove(x)

s #result
['b0', 'c', 'd']
```

When I debug, I found that after 'a0' is removed, the `s` becomes `['b0', '0', 'c', 'd']`, then as I thought, x will be `'b0'`, but it turn out to be `'0'`, so it skipps the `'b0'`, I am wondering the reason behind that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't modify a list while you are iterating over it ([more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list)).

Instead, try filtering the list all at once:

```
s = [x for x in s if x[-1] != '0']
```